# Capture java applet window so I can analyze pixels?

Tags: java

I have a (web) Java Applet which has ever changing graphics. I need to capture this image so that I can analyze pixels - sort of like face recognition software except that's not what I'll be using it for. I know there's ways to capture the entire screens, but I just want to capture the java window.

Comment: Is this an applet that you yourself have created? If so, shouldn't there be easier ways of getting its state? And are you trying to capture the image from code that is within the applet itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) to create an image of any component.